# How to create a new branch for all submodules in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I've just started to work on a new project where the team is maintaining the code as git submodules, I've no previous experience working with Visual Studio 2017 solutions with attached git submodules and now I'm very confused about how to handle new requirements because each module has its own branching system.

The physical folder tree looks like this:

```
-Main Project Folder
--Modules Folder
---Module1 Folder
---Module2 Folder
---Module3 Folder
-Project.sln
```

In this scenario, there are 4 git repos:

1 - Main Project

2 - Module1

3 - Module2

4 - Module3

> Main Project links the other 3 as git submodules

All modules (in most cases) have the same amount of branches with the same naming, here is where my doubt comes up, if for each module exists a branch named *feature1* how they created it? By hand switching between each repo? or there is a way to execute a command like:

> For each submodule, clone it's existing branch named 'feature1' and from it create a new branch named 'feature2'

And my final question is, I'm guessing each submodule branch at the end of the feature/fix development must be merged to a branch in the Main Project... how is that made?

I will appreciate your help understanding this.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no automation in Visual Studio code for your scenario, or any plugin available, however, you can write a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) for the same.

you can fork a shell command for the tasks.

[`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) command will help here.

eg. to create a branch in all submodules (with the same name) you can fire command like this:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout {{sourcebranch}}
git submodule foreach git checkout -b {{newbranch}}
```

Here is a sample file content for visual studio tasks

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "createBranch",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "git submodule foreach `git checkout -b newbranch`",
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You need to find how to pass newbranch name though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `feature2` from `feature1` for all the submodules, you can run in the main project:

```
git submodule foreach 'git branch feature2 feature1'
```

[git submodule foreach](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) makes it possible to manipulate all the submodules at the same time.

As you know, a submodule has its own branches. These branches are NOT merged with the branches of the main project. The main project is interested in only a specific revision of the submodule at a time. A certain commit of the main project's branch records, in its own tree object, that revision of the submodule that it needs.

In the main project, you can run `git ls-tree -r -t HEAD` to explore the tree object of `HEAD`. There is an entry in the format `160000 commit 17cb6ab56b8bbdc7eff94ec981453301c97efb42  Module1`. When the revision of `HEAD` is checked out in the main project, the submodule `Module1` should be synced with its own commit `17cb6ab56b8bbdc7eff94ec981453301c97efb42`. If the revision of `Module1` is changed to a new revision or to an old revision, and you want to commit this change in the main project, you can run in the main project `git add Module1 && git commit`.